# Browser not reading next js file

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript file where no matter where I place it in the includes, the file below it is not being run (in both Chrome and Firefox - probably other browsers as well - just haven't tested them). js files further down are still being run.

The lowest that I have been able to boil it down is:

```
 var robots = {
 init: function(height, width) {
     }
 };
```

And it also happens when I include an empty file. I have also had lines of code inside it as well.

There is a large number of javaScript files included in this page (18 (plus some inline) at this stage and more will come - aggregation and minification are on the list of todo's (but won't be happening in dev for obvious reasons)).

Any further ideas? I've inserted an empty javascript block in the html in the meantime and it works (but is a minor wtf).

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: How do you know that the file hasn't been loaded?

Comment: Which browser? IE has a limit of 32 CSS files. Perhaps there's such a limit for JS files as well. If you use any other browser (or even in the latest IE), you should have some development tools that may report any errors to you.

Comment: Can you make a public live example? Or paste your html code?

Comment: xeon06 & Jacob - most of the other files have similar base code so I get an object not defined error (which happens to be defined in the next file in the list) otherwise I get nothing in the error log.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi for making me look at my code more closely. It was a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man I feel like an idiot.

I had included the javascript with the following syntax error (spot the missing >):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/robots.js"</script>
```

when it should have been:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/robots.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've truly determined that the JavaScript src is correct and that the content hasn't been loaded, check if your browser has any sort of ad blocker installed.  I've seen the issue before where if a URL contains something like "ad" or "robot," that could be enough to trigger it being blocked.

Comment: This sounds like it. The file that causes the problem is called robots.js. I'm working on something else at the moment but I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Unfortunalely not (unless xkcd is also on that blocked list in chrome). I also tried to change the name of the object, with no success.